# C# ASP.NET Project, Linked assemblies dependencies

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I have a web-service project written in Visual Studio 2010, with 3rd party linked library's, which are stored in the bin folder of the project.
If I build and install the project everything seems to work well.

When I run "Clean project" and build after that - VS removes assemblies that are not linked to the project. And when I then run it - I get
"Reference to object is null" exception in functions, which are located in the linked assemblies. I don't get any errors about missing assemblies while compiling.

So, how can I figure out, which assemblies are really needed by the application?

Answer (score 0):

You don't really want to copy the 3rd party dlls directly into the bin folder as a rebuild is going to remove everything there and start again.  Ideally you should have a directory structure something like this

/mysolutionfolder/mysolution.sln

/mysolutionfolder/lib/my3rdparty.dll

/mysolutionfolder/mywebprojectfolder/mywebproject.csproj

Your 3rd party dlls will be in the lib folder and when you add the references in you web project you will do 'Add References' -> browse and then browse to the lib folder and select the dll.  Now when you rebuild a copy of the dll in the lib folder will be copied to the bin directory.